# Freestyle - unwanted gaps

Tags: modeling, rendering, freestyle

I am trying to render a blueprint of a model in Blender 2.74, I am facing an issue with some of the generated lines being non-continuos, this is the result:

[image: result image]

I followed this tutorial: [Tutorial: Blender 3D #4 - Blueprint (Freestyle)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I6xmgLBeA4).

How can I get rid of these gaps in the lines?

Comment: Here is the link to the blend file incase someone wants to give it a try https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g3s8-cUC8NWU5EdElqcWlXNHc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks in Freestyle are almost exclusively caused by clipping/mesh intersections. Alternatively, it could be that you have a minimum stroke length set. Check for intersections in your model at those areas. If that is not the problem, you will need to share your file for it to be determined.

Comment: I checked the model, couldn't find any issues ( My experience is limited with Blender). Here is the link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g3s8-cUC8NWU5EdElqcWlXNHc/view?usp=sharing     Thanks

Comment: It looks like the problem is broken chaining. I though it might be due to the topology, but adding more loops didn't help. It works fine from some other angles. If you render the tools on their own, they work fine. So it's something to do with with having everything visible...but I have no idea what that could be.